# Best way to get the international country ISD phone codes

Tags: c#

I am looking for any routine which will give me the ISD code for any country. I searched Google a lot but found nothing similar. I tried to do it in this way:

```
 public string ISDCode(string strCountryCode)
    {
        string countryCode = "";
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        string url = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso/CountryIntPhoneCode?";
        url = url + "sCountryISOCode=" + strCountryCode;
        xdoc.Load(url);
        countryCode =  xdoc.DocumentElement.InnerText.ToString();
        return countryCode;
    }
```

I use this [web service](http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso)

but often it is not accessible. Please guide me how I can get the ISD code for any country. I will just pass country code only. For example I will pass 'CA' for Canada and the routine will give me the Canada ISO code. Please help. thanks.

Comment: http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetISD this one seems to be free

Comment: i often saw 3rd party free web services some time work and some time not. so i used one in my code. few days back it worked but now it is not working. so 3rd party web service is risky for use. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a webservice for some reason, I'd go to Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

...or here:

http://countrycode.org/

...and build my own lookup table from that. In fact writing a script to generate that automatically sounds kind of fun to me. :)

Comment: i want to do it programmatically...any suggestion. can u give me any complete routine which will do it.

Comment: @Thomas I'm suggesting you do it programmatically. The new website I've linked to has a table that will be easier to parse than the Wikipedia one. Paste it into a text file and write something to extract the data and output something useful, like a Dictionary<string, string> that contains all the entries. As yours seems like a niche case, I doubt there's any routines written to do this already, you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

One of our application we are displaying countries with their ISD codes in the dropdown. I am sharing here **JSON** file which we used.

It contains almost all countries with their name, country code, and ISD code. 
https://gist.github.com/iamswapnilsonar/0e1868229e98cc27a6d2e3487b44f7fa

Hope this is helpful to you! Let me know if you have any suggestion/correction.